Attribute Error, 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get' Django-HTMX
I'm building a homepage that includes a contact-us form. This contact-us form element should be reusable across multiple pages, so I've used HTMX to try incorporate. However am receiving the following error, which I can't make sense of because I'm submitting POST data.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/contactus

Django Version: 4.2.13
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'accounts',
 'dashboard']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 67, in render
    context = context or self.get_context()
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 322, in get_context
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors().copy()
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 358, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 196, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 433, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 440, in _clean_fields
    value = bf.initial if field.disabled else bf.data
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 135, in data
    return self.form._widget_data_value(self.field.widget, self.html_name)
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 220, in _widget_data_value
    return widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, html_name)
  File "/Users/robrobrob/Desktop/Projects/Trolleys/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 297, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /contactus
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'


** Forms.py **
This file contains the form logic
class Contact_Us_Form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        label="Name",
        max_length=60,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    sender = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
        label="Email"
    )
    message_content = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label="Your message"
    )


** Views.py **
for the form element
def contact_us_response(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Contact_Us_Form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect("partials/success.html")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Something's broke")
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form = Contact_Us_Form()
        return render(request, "partials/contact.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        form = Contact_Us_Form()
        return HttpResponse("Method not allowed", status=405)

** Views.py **
for the homepage
def home(request):
    form = Contact_Us_Form()
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', {'form': form})


** Urls.py **
urlpatterns = [
 path("", include('dashboard.urls')), # the homepage is rendered via separate urls.py on the 'dashboard' app's urls.py
 path('contactus', Contact_Us_Form, name="contact"),
]


** home.html relevant section from homepage **
 <form id="contact-us-form" hx-post="{% url 'contact' %}" hx-target="#contact-us-form">
{{ form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary w-20" >Submit</button>
</form>

** contact.html **
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="name" class="form-label d-inline">Name <p class="text-secondary d-inline">*</p></label>
        {{ form.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email <p class="text-secondary d-inline">*</p></label>
        {{ form.sender }}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="message" class="form-label">How can we help you? <p class="text-secondary d-inline">*</p></label>
        {{ form.message_content }}
        <p class="small text-secondary">We'll hold your details in accordance with our Privacy Policy. 
            This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Google Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms Of Service</a> apply.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary w-20">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

My troubleshooting process
Don't understand why POST data is throwing a GET error. Also don't really understand how WSGI is coming into this picture. It looks like similar errors have been raised on SO before without resolution.

Added if/else handling for GET scenarios in the views.py
Added (and removed) method="POST" and action="contacts" to override this behaviour. No success
Tried changing form = Contact_Us_Form(request.POST) into form = Contact_Us_Form(data = request.POST). No success
Reviewed network inspect tab for payload and headers. Request Method = POST and payload includes expected fields (name, sender, message content)
Added and removed CSRF references throughout the document. This is not the source of the error


You should link the path to the view so contact_us_response, not the form (Contact_Us_Form`):
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '', include('dashboard.urls')
    ),  # the homepage is rendered via separate urls.py on the 'dashboard' app's urls.py
    path('contactus', contact_us_response, name='contact'),
]

Thank you! You hit the nail on the head, this solution worked a charm. I can't believe I was pointing to the form instead of the URL. Lifesaver
